# TypeError: projects.map is not a function (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Components

```js
const Pcards = ({ projects }) => {
     return (
         <div>
             <CardColumns>
                 {projects.map((projects) => (
                    <Card>
                       <Card.Img variant="top" src={"http://localhost:8000" + projects.images[0].file_path + projects.images[0].file_name + projects.images[0].file_type} />
```

Pages

```js
class Projects extends Component {

    state = {
        projects:[]
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/projects')
       .then(res => res.json())
       .then((data) => {
         this.setState({ projects: data })
       })
       .catch(console.log)
    }

    render () {
      return (
         <Pcards projects = {this.state.projects} />
      );
    }
}
```

New to react and this code returns

> TypeError: projects.map is not a function

This appears to be compiling just fine on my partner's end since he written this code and I'm trying to expand on his work.

I've seen other similar posts but unable to find a fix. Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: Is your api not returning an array? That's the only thing I can think of from your code.

Comment: It is returning an array.

Comment: For now, try putting `Array.isArray(projects) && projects.map((projects) ` at line 8 in Pcards, that should prevent the error, but there is definitely something weird going on. Based on what you said and the code you posted, projects shouldn't ever be a non-array. Might also be a good idea to log the data returned from the fetch and the type of the data `typeof data`

Comment: This got rid of the error but now I have to figure out why it isn't returning anything on the browser. Appreciate the help up to this point!

Comment: If that got rid of the issue, then projects is somehow not an array. Can you put `console.log(this.state.projects, typeof this.state.projects)` in your render function in Projects and post the results? Also, is your api on port 5000 or port 8000, because I see instances of both in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two mistakes in your `Projects` class.
1- .catch error handling syntax was wrong
2- you were not checking the fetched data

```js
class Projects extends Component {
  state = {
    projects: []
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/projects')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        if (data && data.length) {    // checking the data
          this.setState({ projects: data })
        } else {
          console.log("Projects fetch failed, check your api code!")
        }
      })
      .catch(e => console.log(e));   // corrected error catch
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Pcards projects={this.state.projects} />
    );
  }
}
```

You can also edit your `Pcards` component code. You are already using a property called `projects` and you are mapping it, calling the argument `projects` too. That is not a good practice. If you are mapping `projects` name the item as `project` or `projectItem`.

`projects.map((project) => ...`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
class Projects extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            projects:[]
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do I need to edit the components file: Pcards if I make this change?

Comment: No... no other change required

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't fix the issue then =/

Comment: That is only a potential issue if you aren't using Create React App (or babel+pollyfils) and are on IE or safari https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Class_fields#Public_fields

Comment: can you post log after const Pcards = ({ projects }) => { console.log(projects)